# Original route doesn't work

Tags: c++, compression, huffman-code

I have this code, but when i run the program the first cin doesn't work
I don't understand the reason

```
    /*Metodo che calcola in byte la differenza tra il file non compresso e quello compresso aprendo
i due files, calcolando la lunghezza e facendo la differenza*/
void Huffman::rate_compression(){
    cout<<"Inserisci il percorso del file originale:\t"<<endl;
    string route;
    cin>>route;
    ifstream filenoncompresso;
    filenoncompresso.open("route",ifstream::in);
    filenoncompresso.seekg(0,filenoncompresso.end);
    int lenght1=filenoncompresso.tellg();
    filenoncompresso.seekg(0,filenoncompresso.beg);
    filenoncompresso.close();
    ifstream filecompresso;
    string way;
    route.erase(route.end()-4,route.end());
    way=route+".aa";
    filecompresso.open("way",ifstream::in);
    filecompresso.seekg(0,filecompresso.end);
    int lenght2=filecompresso.tellg();
    lenght2-=1028;
    filecompresso.seekg(0,filecompresso.beg);
    cout<<"La differenza in byte tra il file non compresso e il file compresso e': "<<lenght1-lenght2<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you please give us more details?

Comment: Did you mean `filenoncompresso.open(route,ifstream::in);` rather than     `filenoncompresso.open("route",ifstream::in);`?  One opens the file whose name you read from stdin, the other opens the file called "route".

Comment: Maybe, instead of `filenoncompresso.open("route",ifstream::in);`, try: `filenoncompresso.open(route,ifstream::in);` without ""

Comment: When i paste the route the first time is ok, but the program should ask me the route another time

If i use route and not "route" they give me an error

Comment: This is the sort of problem you need to solve yourself.  See [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert for advice on how to proceed.